# polynomial word problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, applications

[image]

My answer is wrong... I understand what I did was found the volume of the pool (cubic feet) I am supposed to get square feet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint:  how many sides does the pool have?  Each of these are rectangles, what is the area of each?  Then add them up.